# Problem understanding Permission Set xml in Eclipse IDE

Tags: permission-sets, force.com-ide

I have a Permission Set which has access to some Classes and Pages and one Custom Field on the Account object.

When I am trying to see the file in Eclipse IDE, it shows as just the following, even after trying to re-synchronize and update the file from server. Is it a bug with Eclipse Force.com IDE?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <hasActivationRequired>false</hasActivationRequired>
    <label>BPGovernance Permission Set</label>
</PermissionSet>
```

Where are my class and field permissions?

**Edit:**

Created a fresh project and took just the Permission Set only. Still same result.

**Edit:**

Added the classes and pages and the custom field components to the project. Now I see correct xml, which is very strange because in my original  project (which gave the empty xml), all these classes and fields were present too.
Now it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<classAccesses>
    <apexClass>BPGConfigController</apexClass>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</classAccesses>
<classAccesses>
    <apexClass>MetadataController</apexClass>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</classAccesses>
<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>false</editable>
    <field>Account.FormulaHyperlinkFieldNew__c</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>
<hasActivationRequired>false</hasActivationRequired>
<label>BPGovernance Permission Set</label>
<pageAccesses>
    <apexPage>BusinessPartnerDetails</apexPage>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</pageAccesses>
</PermissionSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Force.com IDE (Eclipse), you need to refresh whole permission set folder (not the permission set file itself) in order to get complete XML and dependencies. Profiles also have similar behavior.

Comment: Thanks but didn't work for me